# Hadoop FAILED Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Tags: java, hadoop

I am using Hadoop MapReduce to calculate each year's min and max value, but when I run the program, I get the error: `FAILED Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5`

I think this is because there are null values in my data because the program runs fine when there is no null value.

Therefore, in my map function, I write if statement to check whether there is a header and if there is a null value:

```
 public static class ExposureMapper
        extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, MinMaxExposure> {

    private Text year = new Text();
    private double minexposure;
    private Double maxexposure;

    private MinMaxExposure outPut = new MinMaxExposure();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            //Some condition satisfying it is header
            if (value.toString().contains("Product")) {
                return;
            } else if(value.toString()==null) {
               return;
            }
            else{
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] solarFields = value.toString().split(",");

        year.set(solarFields[2]);
        minexposure = Double.parseDouble(solarFields[5]);
        maxexposure = Double.parseDouble(solarFields[5]);

        try {
            outPut.setMinExposure(minexposure);
            outPut.setMaxExposure(maxexposure);
            context.write(year, outPut);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But the same error happens...
Is it because `value.toString()==null` is not a proper way to check null value?

EDIT:

```
19/06/07 00:14:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1527224104960_0812_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at com.mycompany.hw1.SolarMinMax$ExposureMapper.map(SolarMinMax.java:50)
    at com.mycompany.hw1.SolarMinMax$ExposureMapper.map(SolarMinMax.java:23)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:177)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:171)
```

Comment: A stack trace will be useful Shin. Also you should use `value.toString().isEmpty` to check null values.

Comment: Add the string you are splitting.  My guess is that that there are not as many results as you think!

Comment: @MilanDesai I try value.toString().isEmpty, but it's not work :(

Comment: @Micromuncher What do you mean Add the string you are splitting? thank you.

Comment: Can you please post stacktrace. it will get us understand at which point you see ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @MilanDesai I edit the complete error above, is this the stacktrace you indicate?

Comment: `minexposure = Double.parseDouble(solarFields[5]);` is throwing the error because the array returned is "short", in other words, there are fewer than 5 comma delimited fields.  So - I want to see the string you pass to the split function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `value.toString().split(",");` has has fewer than six elements, `solarFields[5]` will not be an element, and so you'll see a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Immediately after creating `solarFields` you should check its length:

```
if (solarFields == null || solarFields.length < 6) {
    return;
}
```

You also want to make sure that `Double.parseDouble(solarFields[5]);` doesn't throw a `NumberFormatException`:

```
Double exposure;
try {
    exposure = Double.parseDouble(solarFields[5]);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return;
}
```